# BlockUI bad performance

Tags: jquery, blockui

I am having serious performance issues with BlockUI and ASP.NET AJAX on my aspx page.

I'm trying simple element blocking but it is fading in with a a lag/delay. Do html errors on page affect blockUI?

I'm blocking a large div spanning well above the browser vertically. The unblock works great for the same page (without any delay/lag). In case of a timeout on my Update Panel, the fadein works good too but just comes with a lag.

```
function blockMaster(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ftMaster').block({message:"<h2>Just a moment...</h2>"});
        $('#<%=btnAJAX.ClientID%>').attr("disabled",true);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that HTML errors would prevent `blockUI` from working at all, were they serious. What happens when you comment out the `block()` call from `$(document).ready()` and call it manually via Firebug once the page has loaded completely? Is there still a delay? Do you have other handler functions that are being called on the `ready` event? Who calls `blockMaster()`, and when?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nick. There isn't any delay when I block the div from firebug console. I just put document.ready there as I read somewhere it is good practise. I am just calling the block function on an Async Postback by a asp.net server control outside my updatepanel, I check for the postback control id and isinasyncpostback() and block the div if its matched.

Comment: Also when I test in IE, there isn't even a delayed fade, it just toggles to visible, fadeout works good.

Comment: The function you pass to $(document).ready() is called once during the initial loading of your page, when the DOM tree has been constructed (see http://api.jquery.com/ready/). It IS good practice to put JS initialization code there, however you usage doesn't make sense to me. You either call blockUI() on page load, OR as a postback. Try removing the $(document).ready() wrapping.